# Customizing tooltip using ggplotly and geom_density

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I'm trying to create a tooltip that shows the density as well as the x-axis information using ggplot and ggplotly.

Using the mtcars data sets, I wanted to just create a tooltip for the density of the mpg that was cleaner.

The basic plot I was trying to create was using

```
data(mtcars)
ggplotly(
  ggplot(mtcars)+
    geom_density(
      aes(x = mpg,
          y = ..scaled..)
    )+
    scale_y_continuous(
      name = 'Counters', 
      sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * (max_dens/max_hist)*10, name = 'Density'))
  )
```

which produces
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilwny.png)

This tooltip is working, but I would essentially like to change the 'scaled' to something else. I've tried added the text to the aes like:

```
ggplotly(
  ggplot(mtcars)+
    geom_density(
      aes(x = mpg,
          y = ..scaled..,
          text = paste('testing',mpg))
    )
)
```

But that just creates a new density for each mpg.

The full example I want to use is combining both a histogram and density like:

```
data(mtcars)
nbins = 20
df = mtcars
min.brea <- round_any(min(df$mpg), diff(range(df$mpg))/nbins, floor)
max.brea <- round_any(max(df$mpg), diff(range(df$mpg))/nbins, ceiling)
breaks <- seq(min.brea, max.brea, diff(range(df$mpg/nbins)))
histdata <- hist(df$mpg, breaks=breaks, plot=FALSE, right=FALSE)

max_hist <- max(histdata$counts)
max_dens <- max(density(df$mpg)$y)


ggplotly(
  ggplot(mtcars)+
    geom_histogram(
      aes(x = mpg,
          text = paste('Testing', mpg)
      ),
      bins = 30,
      color = 'black',
      fill = 'white'
    )+
    geom_density(
      aes(x = mpg,
          y = ..scaled..*(max_hist),
          text = paste('Testing', mpg, max_hist*..scaled..))
    )+
    scale_y_continuous(
      name = 'Counters', 
      sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * (max_dens/max_hist), name = 'Density')),
  tooltip = 'text')
```

But this really messes up the tooltip.

I was hoping there was a way to specify the tooltips for each one individually to be cleaner on the output side of things. Eventually this will go into an Rshiny app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't combine columns from the original data with columns from the data after the `stat` is applied. The only reason you don't get an error when doing `paste('Testing', mpg, max_hist * ..scaled..))` is that in this case the dataset `mpg` from the global environment is used which results in the messed up tooltip. Instead use the `x` column computed by the `stat`, i.e. do `paste('Testing',..x.., max_hist * ..scaled..))`. Additionally note that I switched to `after_stat` as the `..` notation was deprecated in `ggplot2 3.4.0`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(
      x = mpg,
      text = paste("Testing", mpg)
    ),
    bins = 30,
    color = "black",
    fill = "white"
  ) +
  geom_density(
    aes(
      x = mpg,
      y = max_hist * after_stat(scaled),
      text = after_stat(paste("Testing", x, max_hist * scaled))
    )
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Counters",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * (max_dens / max_hist), name = "Density")
  )

ggplotly(tooltip = "text")
```

[image]